# not able to login heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, heroku

i was trying to login to heroku to push my app and until yesterday it was working but now it is giving me errors related to json version.

this is the log created after command heroku login

```
This is the legacy Heroku CLI. Please install the new CLI from https://cli.heroku.com
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2275:in `check_version_conflict': can't activate json-1.8.2, already activated json-1.8.3 (Gem::LoadError)
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1404:in `activate'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:89:in `block in require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:88:in `each'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:88:in `require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/heroku-3.99.1/lib/heroku/cli.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/heroku-3.99.1/bin/heroku:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/heroku:22:in `load'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/heroku:22:in `<main>'
```

my ruby version is 2.3.3 and rails 5.0.3

Thank you

Comment: Try running `gem cleanup` and followed by `gem update json`

Comment: Thanks @Pavan..it worked

Comment: Glad to help! Will write it as an answer so you can accept it :)

Comment: sure please do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `check_version_conflict': can't activate json-1.8.2, already activated
>   json-1.8.3 (Gem::LoadError)

This is due to *bundler* trying to install `json-1.8.2` when there is `json-1.8.3` *already installed*. This is because *bundler* will use `Gemfile.lock` to install *specified gem versions* of gems.

You should do `gem cleanup` and followed by `gem update json`. This will update the `json` to *latest version* in `Gemfile.lock` and will resolve the problem.